# Function where order of integration cannot be reversed

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Our professor gave us the following problem to give us an example where we cannot switch the order of integration. However, I am stuck on the last part, so maybe someone can give me an answer.

Let $i = 1,2,\dots$ and $\phi_i: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions with $\mathrm{supp}(\phi_i) \subset (2^{-i}, 2^{1-i})$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi_i = 1$.
Then we define $$f(x,y) := \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}(\phi_i(x) - \phi_{i+1}(x))\phi_i(y).$$
I already managed to prove that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,0)\}$.

The main problem is the following, however; we are meant to show that

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}{\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\right)\mathrm{d}y} = 0,$$ but $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}{\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y)\mathrm{d}y\right)\mathrm{d}x} = 1.$$

The first result is what I also obtain, but I seem to be doing something wrong, as I obtain 0 for the second integral as well.

Comment: Are you bringing the series out of the integrals? (That could be your error)

Comment: $\int \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}(\phi_i- \phi_{i+1})=\int\phi_1=1.$

Comment: @BrianMoehring I think was is it... What a silly mistake, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I *expect* you are doing:

$$\begin{align*}
\int_\mathbb{R}\left(\int_\mathbb{R} f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\,\mathrm{d}y &{{}\color{red} ={}} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_\mathbb{R}\left(\int_\mathbb{R} (\phi_i(x)-\phi_{i+1}(x))\phi_i(y)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\,\mathrm{d}y \\ 
& = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_\mathbb{R}(1-1)\phi_i(y)\,\mathrm{d}y = 0
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
\int_\mathbb{R}\left(\int_\mathbb{R} f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y\right)\,\mathrm{d}x &{{}\color{red} ={}} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_\mathbb{R}\left(\int_\mathbb{R} (\phi_i(x)-\phi_{i+1}(x))\phi_i(y)\,\mathrm{d}y\right)\,\mathrm{d}x \\ 
& = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_\mathbb{R}(\phi_i(x)-\phi_{i+1}(x))\,\mathrm{d}x \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^\infty (1-1)= 0
\end{align*}$$

In both cases, the first equality, marked in red, isn't justified.  It's a common mistake, but a major one, as the assumptions that allow us to swap discrete sums with integrals are closely related to the assumptions that allow us to swap the order of integrals (if you know counting measure and the Lebesgue integral, you can directly see this comparison).

Instead, we need to carefully consider the integrals and avoid swapping either integrals or sums.

- For a fixed $y \in (0,1)$, there is exactly one $i_0$ for which $\phi_{i_0}(y) \neq 0$, so
  $$\int_\mathbb{R}\sum_{i=1}^\infty (\phi_i(x)-\phi_{i+1}(x))\phi_i(y)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_\mathbb{R}(\phi_{i_0}(x)-\phi_{i_0+1}(x))\phi_{i_0}(y)\,\mathrm{d}x = \phi_{i_0}(y)(1-1)=0$$
- For a fixed $x \in (0,1)$, there is exactly one $i_0$ for which $\phi_{i_0}(x) \neq 0$, **so if $i_0 > 1$**,
  $$\int_\mathbb{R}\sum_{i=1}^\infty (\phi_i(x)-\phi_{i+1}(x))\phi_i(y)\,\mathrm{d}y = \int_\mathbb{R}\phi_{i_0}(x)(\phi_{i_0}(y)-\phi_{i_0-1}(y))\,\mathrm{d}y = \phi_{i_0}(x)(1-1) = 0$$ **but if $i_0=1$, we have**
  $$\int_\mathbb{R}\sum_{i=1}^\infty (\phi_i(x)-\phi_{i+1}(x))\phi_i(y)\,\mathrm{d}y = \int_\mathbb{R}\phi_1(x)\phi_1(y)\,\mathrm{d}y$$

It's this last case, when $\frac12 < x < 1$, that makes the integral $\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x$ nonzero.

---

*To summarize one way to see the difference we saw above we can just note* $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty (\phi_i(x)-\phi_{i+1}(x))\phi_i(y) = \phi_1(x)\phi_1(y) + \sum_{i=2}^\infty \phi_i(x)(\phi_i(y) - \phi_{i-1}(y))$$
where the convergence is pointwise.